# The following classes could not be instantiated: Open Class,Show Exception,Clear Cache?

Tags: android

I'm new to make android app.

It says:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)


 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout$1   at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.<init>(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:93)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.<init>(BridgeActionBar.java:84)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.<init>(AppCompatActionBar.java:56) Copy stack to clipboard
```

---

I'm using Android Studio 1.2 for Mac.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: can you please more specific to your question? Tell us what you doing, some codes?

Comment: i just wanted to follow this; <https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html>   but could not run my app on the emulator.